# weblogic managed server application cannot read arguments supplied

Tags: java, web-applications, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have an application that is deployed to a WebLogic Server 12c. Application uses statements like

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(System.getProperty("PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH").concat(Configuration.getFS()).concat("log4j.properties"));
```

I tried to give the arguments in the following way:  Environment > Servers > [Name of Server] > Configuration > Server Start, and add the arguments to the Arguments field.

But when I tried to read the argument I provided in the statement System.getProperty("PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH"), I get null in return. I could not find the reason why I cannot get these parameters.

I even put the argument in the startWebLogicServer.cmd file but that did not change anything.

I deployed the same war to Tomcat, and I did not get the error above. So what is the reason for this behavior in Weblogic?

Comment: The options in `Server Start` are only applied when the server is started via the node manager. When you put the arguments directly in the .cmd file, did you make sure they were in JAVA_OPTIONS?

Comment: so you say if I started the server via the command line, these arguments does not take effect?

Comment: Correct if you start the server on the command line the `Server Start` options don't apply